# Apache update error

Tags: apache, curl, centos6, ca, easyapache-4

```
root@server.mydomain.com [~]# yum update Loaded plugins:
fastestmirror, security, universal-hooks Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile Could not retrieve
mirrorlist
https://mirrors.iuscommunity.org/mirrorlist?repo=ius-el6&arch=x86_64&protocol=http
error was 14: PYCURL ERROR 77 - "error setting certificate verify
locations:   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt   CApath: none"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: ius
root@server.mydomain.com [~]#
```

Server installed with centos 6.9, EasyApche4.
I have tried many solutions by searching online, not success. Could any one provide whats actually need to fix the error?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for you tech...